# How to import/export developer story

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, developer-story, cv-export, cv-import

The developer story UI is done well but I bet that many developers prefer to type in the structured content in YAML or some other format. At least I gave up after editing three or four items. Please give us the data and let us upload a full story so we can edit it an editor of our choice.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, its a nice idea but unlikely something we're going to focus on right now. I'll let you know if there is any change in it's priority.

Comment: @Kit any progress on that? Do you accept Pull Requests? ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you export StackOverflow Developer Story data?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416702/how-do-you-export-stackoverflow-developer-story-data). Let's consolidate the questions about exporting the dev story to the newest one as the story is being sunset.